# Is "unix" restricted keyword in C?

Tags: c, unix, gcc, keyword

This code does not compile for me on GCC version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)

```
main() {
  int unix;
}
```

I've checked the C keywords list and "unix" is not one of them.

Why am I getting the following error?

```
unix.c:2: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`unix` is not a identifier reserved by the Standard.

If you compile with `-std=c89` or `-std=c99` the gcc compiler will accept the program as you expected.

From gcc manual ( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html ), the emphasis is mine.

> ... However,
>   historically system-specific macros
>   have had names with no special prefix;
>   for instance, **it is common to find
>   unix defined on Unix systems**. For all
>   such macros, GCC provides a parallel
>   macro with two underscores added at
>   the beginning and the end. If unix is
>   defined, __unix__ will be defined too.
>   There will never be more than two
>   underscores; the parallel of _mips is
>   __mips__.

Answer (score 13):

unix is one of the defines the preprocessor uses in gcc 
to get a list of defs use

```
gcc -dM -E  -x c /dev/null
```

(*-dM* tells gcc to debugdump the defs *-E* tells it to stop after prepreocessing and *-x c /dev/null* tells him to pretend /dev/null is a c file)

Comment: shorter and easier: `echo | gcc -E -dD -`

Comment: @mirabilos Doesn't work. gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: @ВладиславКороль probably forgot the `-` at the end

Comment: @mirabilos Yes.

Answer (score 12):

Run your code through the preprocessor to find out what the compiler is actually seeing:

```
gcc -E unix.c
```

Then see if your variable `unix` is preserved or converted by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 7):

It is not a keyword.

It is a **predefined macro to identify the type of system**. On Unix and Unix like systems it is defined to be `1`.

To disable this use the `-ansi` option:

> In C mode, this is equivalent to -std=c89. In C++ mode, it is equivalent to -std=c++98.
>   This turns off certain features of GCC that are incompatible with ISO C90 (when compiling C code), or of standard C++ (when compiling C++ code), such as the "asm" and "typeof" keywords, and **predefined macros such as "unix"** and "vax" that identify the type of system you are using. It also enables the undesirable and rarely used ISO trigraph feature.  For the C compiler, it disables recognition of C++ style // comments as well as the "inline" keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gona take a wild stab at this and guess that gcc effectively #defined unix as 1 on UNIX systems.

try

```
main(){ 
  printf("%d", unix); 
}
```

and see what you get.

Comment: @Steve: see pmg's answer to see why `gcc` in non-standard mode tends to define this macro.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no `unix` is not a reserved word in C.

However, the symbol `unix` is most likely defined by the preprocessor either because you include a header file or because the compiler defines it.

Comment: It should be noted that it's **broken** and nonconformant behavior for gcc to do this.