# Variable named 'unix' has value 1

Tags: c, unix

If I write this program -

```
main(){printf("%d",unix);}
```

this compiles correctly, and prints `1`, although I had expected an 'unix undeclared' or similar error. But if I change to this-

```
main(){printf("%d",blah);}
```

This gives error-

```
error: 'blah' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

as expected.

So, why does `unix` does not generate an error, and why is it's value 1? I tried Googling but nothing came up.

Comment: preprocessor define?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770322/is-unix-restricted-keyword-in-c

Answer (score 1):

```
#undef unix
int main(void)
{printf("%d\n",unix);
return 0;
}
```

---

Fails to compile (even after `#include <stdio.h>`, so, it must be some builtin preprocessor `~#define` Compiler output:

```
unix.c: In function ‘main’:
unix.c:4:16: error: ‘unix’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 {printf("%d\n",unix);
```